# How can I remove three characters at the end of a string in PHP?

Tags: php, string

How can I remove three characters at the end of a string in PHP?

"abcabcabc" would become "abcabc"!

Comment: You might find [`s($str)->cutEnd(3)`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str/blob/ea3e40132e9d4ce27da337dae6286f2478b15f56/src/Str.php#L341) helpful, as found in [this standalone library](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str). This is Unicode or multibyte safe.

Answer (score 857, accepted):

Just do:

```
echo substr($string, 0, -3);
```

You don't need to use a `strlen` call, since, as noted in [the substr documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php):

> If length is given and is negative, then that many characters will be omitted from the end of string

Answer (score 51):

```php
<?php echo substr("abcabcabc", 0, -3); ?>
```

Answer (score 5):

```
<?php echo substr($string, 0, strlen($string) - 3); ?>
```

Comment: The strlen() is unnecessary.