# Strip last 3 characters in echo

Tags: php

i have a php function here `echo $balance['credit'];`

which outputs numbers like this `34.60000`

I dont want it to have the 3 extra 0's so how do i strip the last 3 ?

I tried using this here but didnt work. [strip characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915753/how-can-i-remove-3-characters-at-the-end-of-a-string-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [printf](https://www.php.net/printf) to do formatted printing.  E.g., `echo sprintf('%.2f', $balance['credit']);`

Comment: How can i get that extra 0?

Comment: That's good.  The `.1` portion describes how many numbers after the decimal point, so use `%.2f` instead

Comment: yup i figured that one out! haha

Comment: `echo sprintf()` is an "antipattern". There is absolutely no reason that anyone should ever write `echo sprintf()` in any code for any reason -- it should be `printf()` without `echo` every time.

Comment: @mickmackusa: do you have documentation for such an absolute claim? Perhaps a link to a patterns guide that would provide other good recommendations?

Comment: No, I know of no book of PHP anti-patterns.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
echo number_format($balance['credit'], 2, '.', '')
```

See [demo](https://eval.in/101794)

Comment: I guess this is the preferred PHP mechanism?