# How to eliminate/remove the last character from a string in PHP

Tags: php, string, character

How can I remove the last character dynamically from a PHP string variable?

```
$string = '10,20,30,';
echo $string;
```

**Available output:**

```
10,20,30,
```

**Required output:**

```
10,20,30
```

Comment: echo rtrim($string,',');

Comment: `echo substr($string, 0, strlen($string)-1);`

Comment: This is one of the top hits for `site:stackoverflow.com end of character PHP`. [The duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053830/how-do-i-remove-all-specific-characters-at-the-end-of-a-string-in-php) also has other methods, incl. using regular expressions, `mb_substr`, and `trim`.

Comment: [An answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915753/how-can-i-remove-three-characters-at-the-end-of-a-string-in-php/4915787#4915787) covers ***unconditionally*** removing the last character (that ***this*** question is if taken literally as written): `substr($string, 0, -1);`

Answer (score 7):

`rtrim($string, ",");` removes a comma at the **end** of the string.

[PHP.net rtrim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php)

`trim($string, ",");` removes a comma at the **beginning and end** of a string.

[PHP.net trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)

You can also use implode if you're working with arrays:

[PHP.net implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

Example from php.net:

```
<?php
    $array = array('lastname', 'email', 'phone');
    $comma_separated = implode(",", $array);

    echo $comma_separated; // lastname,email,phone

    // Empty string when using an empty array:
    var_dump(implode('hello', array())); // string(0) ""
?>
```

Comment: Right! C'mon you just copied my answer. No hard feelings though. It is fun to see people grasp for points. Go for it!

Comment: No, I thought about implode cause the string looks a lot like it's coming from an array

Comment: @RST: What do you mean? You posted your answer 100 seconds later. Did something happen in the 5 minute edit grace period (in the remaining 200 seconds (3 min 20 secs))?

Comment: this doesn't answer the question though. This will remove any commas that are at the end, the question just says the last one. eg `x,,,,` should be `x,,,` but trim will return `x`

Answer (score 3):

`echo substr($string, 0, strlen($string)-1);`

- *[substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)*
- *[strlen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php)*

Comment: why 2 functions when it can be done with 1? Is it faster?

Comment: What if you don't know the character to delete?

Comment: Seems like he does :)

Comment: I prefer methods with generic applicability.

Comment: This is a better solution @RST no the user did not mention that the last character will always be a comma

Comment: This is a right answer (though somewhat terse). The first two are too closely tied to the specific example string (the text in the question does not say anything about it only being a comma).

Comment: [`strlen` is claimed to be unnecessary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915753/how-can-i-remove-three-characters-at-the-end-of-a-string-in-php#comment32990960_4915775) (PHP version dependent?). [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915753/how-can-i-remove-three-characters-at-the-end-of-a-string-in-php/4915779#4915779).

Answer (score 1):

**Yes!** I have gotten an answer:

```
$string = chop($string, ",");

echo $string;
```

**Output**

10,20,30

Comment: Yes this is an alias of rtrim() function

Answer (score 0):

You could use [rtrim()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php):

```
rtrim($string, ',');
```

But I think your problem lies elsewhere. It seems like you are adding options to this string in a *for*/*while*/*foreach* loop.

Use this instead:

```
$string = array[];
foreach ($parts as $part) {
  $string[] = $part;
}
$string = implode($string, ',');
```

Answer (score -1):

If PHP > 7.1 then

```
$string[-1] = PHP_EOL;
```

[DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1054edba9b7d770473fad1b1dee6b81148556f97)

Comment: This may work, but can you add something to substantiate the claim, e.g. one or more references? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52601696/edit), not here in comments (***************************************** ***without*** ***************************************** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: This **overwrites the last character** in the string with a newline character, it does not remove the last character.