# Is there any way to delete characters from the original file using fwrite?

Tags: php, xml, file

I am creating a php code that makes an XML in a new file or adds an element to an existing one. The problem is that if the file is existing, i have to delete the closing xml tag.

This is my first time here, I dont know if i am doing it the right way.
Thanks!

This is the code i have and i dont know how to delete the last 10 characters () when im adding an element.

```
if (!file_exists($folderPath)) {
        mkdir($folderPath, 0777);
        $fp=fopen($folderPath."/cistell.xml", "a+");                
        fwrite($fp, $text);
        fclose($fp);
    } else {
        $fp=fopen($folderPath."/cistell.xml", "a+");
        fwrite($fp, $textAdd);
        fclose($fp);
    }
```

Comment: _"dont know if i am doing it the right way"_ - manipulating XML using string/file manipulation techniques, is hardly ever the right way. You should use a DOM Parser for this.

Comment: If you really need to: open the file with `r+` mode and set the position with `fseek($fp, -10, SEEK_END);`.

Comment: The variables `$text` and `$textAdd` are presumably strings, and if so you can use [string manipulation functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4915787/231316) instead

Comment: @ChrisHaas If the file is large, it's better not to load/save it.

Comment: @Olivier, I agree, however it appears they are writing a string to the file, so I figured they could just manipulate the string before writing it to disk, instead of trimming the file afterward.

Answer (score 0):

You need to open the file differently if it exists and seek before the ending part.

The following example adds an entry with the current time to an XML log file on every execution.

```php
$logFile = __DIR__.'/data/log.xml';
$start = "<log>\n";
$end = "</log>\n";

$directory = dirname($logFile);
if (!file_exists($directory)) {
  if (!mkdir($directory, 0777) && !is_dir($directory)) {
    throw new \RuntimeException(sprintf('Directory "%s" was not created', $directory));
  }
}

// check for file
if (file_exists($logFile)) {
  // existing file, open in read+write mode
  $log = new SplFileObject($logFile, 'r+');
  // seek before end
  $log->fseek(-strlen($end), SEEK_END);
} else {
  // new file, open in write mode
  $log = new SplFileObject($logFile, 'w');
  // write start string
  $log->fwrite($start);
}

// use DOM to create the new entry
$document = new DOMDocument();
$entry = $document->createElement('entry');
$entry->textContent = (new DateTime())->format(DateTimeInterface::ISO8601_EXPANDED);

// serialize entry and write to file
$log->fwrite($document->saveXML($entry)."\n");

// write end
$log->fwrite($end);
```